# Displaying polyline shape with height in its profile?

Tags: qgis, profile

Is there a way in QGIS itself or over a plugin to display a polyline shape with heights in its table from a sideview, as in a profile?

I'm talking about QGIS in the version 2.14 and I have simple polyline shapes, which display waste-water and rainwater channel systems.

Every single line has a starting point and end point, and every line feature has a column for the hight at the start and a column for the height at the end point.

I'm thinking about a way to display selected lines in its profile, so you can see the channel from a sideview.

I tried installing a plugin called QGEP that I found by the reference of this picture:

[image]

but this plugin is still experimental and is not working unless I install a demo project and backup a specific folder over a server based program.

Maybe not even understood all of what I have to do, but this plugin seems to go in the right direction with what I can see from the picture.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: ok thank you for welcoming me and for mentioning how i can improve my question. i tryed to put a picture of what i found into the question, maybe that helps.

Comment: The thing your question now lacks is a question, and that should be punctuated using a question mark.  Determining where to place the single question mark is the best way to focus potential answerers on what you are asking.

Comment: oh ok, i thought the question in the title is enough. i ad the question to the text itselfe and try to specify it a little.